# Setting default browser on Xiaomi MIUI phones

Tags: android, default

I am building a browser for Android and cant get **set default browser** to work for **Xiaomi MIUI** phones.

I realised that no other browsers made this work either. The default dialog pops up and I select my browser and tap always, but it fails to set it correctly and falls back to OS default browser.

Since other browsers cant do this either I gave up the idea and now thinking on sending the user to the right settings menu instead for manually setting it. (There is a settings menu for setting default browser in MIUI thats works when doing this manually)

Does someone know the `intent` for opening this menu from my app?

I cant find a complete lists of extra `intents` available.

What I found is the following list but it does not have anything for default browser settings menu.

https://github.com/ChameleonOS/miui_framework/blob/master/java/miui/content/ExtraIntent.java

Comment: The Users needs to choose this from an Intent Chooser. You can't do it programmatically.

Comment: Are you sure? I can open a menu by: 
`Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS); 
startActivity(intent);`
Shows me installed applications. But it looks really strange and unstyled. MIUI developers probably didn't count on people using this.

Comment: Yeah you can open stuff, but the user still needs to select the default apps by himself

Comment: Thats fine, I just want to open the defaults browser menu for the user, then the user can select it themselves.

Comment: I am having the same issue as you. Somehow I found that the UC Browser managed to do this.

Comment: I just downloaded UC browser to my Xiaomi Note 3 and it actually works to set the browser now. When trying to set default I got a message telling me to clear defaults which I did. Maybe this is something that has to be done before (just a guess). It also failed if I didn't check the "defaults checkbox". It also works to set other browsers as default with UC browser.